# Formatting sandbox — please test stuff here

Tags: discussion, formatting

This post is provided so that people can, in the answers and comments below, test formatting features of Academia Stack Exchange.

Comment: what formatting features are we talking about, have I missed something?

Comment: @posdef Markdown formatting… *italics* **bold** ***both*** etc.

Comment: so nothing "new"?

Comment: @posdef no, nothing new… this is a [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) so newcomers in particular can experiment with the Stack Exchange syntax without disturbing regular posts…

Comment: apparently using *edit tags* still causes the question to get bumped.

Answer (score 1):

Hеllo

And this is a community wiki answer, so people can try things out.

Test est Test

Comment: X [‍](http://longer.com)

Comment: ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: @DanielE.Shub welcome to the dark side :)

Comment: [Chat] [Academia] [edit] [main] [academia] [academia.se] [ac]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/139256

Comment: [help] [help/dont-ask]

Comment: @eykanal those are cool shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

`Hello World\`

Single ` back-quote, and a bunch ``` of them.

Backquote marked inside code: `` `ABC`DEF` `` (Does anyone know how to make a code start or end by a backquote?)

1. Numbered
2. List

   ```
   with a code
   ```

   1. and with sublist
3. Well, you can add

   - bullet sublist, if you wish

## Please, don't forget

### Proper titles

#### And subtitles

---

**Pieces of text can be seperated by horizontal rules, too.** *(And the previous text is bold, huh!)*

> Last, but not least, you can quote someone,
>
> ```
> even with a code
> ```

Comment: Do you mean `\`foo`, `bar\``, and `\`foobar\``? If so, the answer is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code). You need to do different things in questions/answers and comments. In comments you use \ to escape the tick, while in questions/answers you use double ticks and spaces

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `\`foo``, `\The answer is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code). In questions/answers you do double backticks with spaces, but in comments you need`` to escape `\`foo``, `` bar` ``, and `` `foobar` ``

Answer (score 0):

$2x + 8 = 4$ Why not LaTeX tag?

Comment: It isn't enabled on ac.SE. I don't think it would be that helpful that often. I think people have mentioned reasons in the past way it is not enabled site wide, but I don't remember the reason.

Comment: The necessary JS library is fairly large, adding to page load time and increasing bandwidth requirements. This was discussed a while back and was determined not to be necessary on this site.

Answer (score 0):

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>